# How to assign a value to a variable and check if it is empty in Windows batch program?

Tags: batch-file, operating-system, command, cmd

Here is the code I wrote:

```
 @echo off
:top
set chkScheduleTime=""
set chkScheduleName=""


set /p scheduleName=Enter the name of the schedule?
cls
set /p scheduleTime=Enter the time to schedule task?
cls


set chkScheduleTime=%scheduleTime =%
set  chkScheduleName=%scheduleName =%

IF /I "%chkScheduleName%"=="" ( 
    set errorMessage=*Name of schedule required 
)


IF /I "%chkScheduleTime%"=="" (
    set errorMessage=%errorMessage% *Time of schedule required 
)

IF NOT defined "%errorMessage%" (

    echo %errorMessage%
    pause
    cls
    goto top
)




echo Schedule Name %scheduleName% 
echo.
echo Time: %scheduleTime%


:end
```

What I am trying to do is accept two parameters from the user which are the task schedule name and the time of the task. Then the program would check the the variables if they are empty and display an error for  the variable that is empty, then prompt the user to re-enter the variable (if one or both were not entered). However the program is displaying the following even if the user entered the schedule name and time:

*Name of schedule required              *Time of schedule required

Also note the following part of the code is used to help check if the values entered by the user are only spaces. Thus its the equivalent of Trim() in regular programming:

```
set chkScheduleTime=%scheduleTime =%
set  chkScheduleName=%scheduleName =%
```

Comment: What is `set chkScheduleTime=%scheduleTime =%` supposed to do? It just clears chkScheduleTime when I try.

Comment: it is supposed to trim the variable that way i can know if the user entered only spaces or not

Comment: That will remove all spaces (once you fix the syntax - See Neil's answer), not just trim spaces from beginning and end. For example - "Hello world" becomes "Helloworld". That doesn't sound like a good idea to me, but maybe it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
set chkScheduleTime=%scheduleTime: =%
```

to strip the spaces from `scheduleTime`.

Also you never reset `errorMessage`, so that once you have an error it won't go away.

Also I think you might want to use `if defined errorMessage`.

Comment: ooh just found out how to reset its set #varname# =